# Highlight Major Value Grid Lines

Tags: amcharts

Is there a setting that I'm missing to highlight major axis grid lines? I've mocked up an example of what I'm trying to do below. The arrows point to what I want, the circle shows what I have. The axis value highlights the day of the week, but not the grid line. I have a feeling that it is considering the 12 pm's as major axis grid lines too.

Here is what I have for the categoryAxis:

```
  "categoryAxis" :
        {
          "equalSpacing" : true,
          "minPeriod" : "hh",
          "parseDates" : true,
          "fontSize" : 24,
          "dateFormats" : [
          {
            period : 'fff',
            format : 'JJ:NN:SS'
          },
          {
            period : 'ss',
            format : 'JJ:NN:SS'
          },
          {
            period : 'mm',
            format : 'JJ:NN'
          },
          {
            period : 'hh',
            format : 'L A'
          },
          {
            period : 'DD',
            format : 'MMM DD\n L A' 
          },
          {
            period : 'WW',
            format : 'MMM DD\n L A'
          },
          {
            period : 'MM',
            format : 'MMM DD\n L A'
          },
          {
            period : 'YYYY',
            format : 'MMM DD\n L A'
          }]
        },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a setting that highlights those lines automatically. You can use a [`guide`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide) to highlight those times by drawing a darker line.

Typically, this is done manually, however you can use the `init` event to automatically do this by having it read the category axis' internal start and end dates and placing the guides as needed:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "init",
    "method": function(e) {
      //get the start and end date objects from the categoryAxis' internal data array
      var startDate = new Date(e.chart.categoryAxis.data[0].category);
      var endDate = new Date(e.chart.categoryAxis.data[e.chart.categoryAxis.data.length - 1].category);
      var guides = [];
      var guideDate;
      //start at midnight
      startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      while (startDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
        guideDate = new Date(startDate);
        guides.push({
          "lineAlpha": 1,
          "lineColor": "#000",
          "date": guideDate
        });
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
      }
      //remove the first guide if it falls outside of the full date range of the axis
      if (guides[0].date.getTime() < e.chart.categoryAxis.data[0].category.getTime()) {
        guides.shift();
      }
      e.chart.categoryAxis.guides = guides;
      e.chart.validateNow(); //draw the guides
    }
  }]
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9534eecfb227ee6356c6ea19211ecc19?editors=0010)

Comment: Perfect! That's just what I was looking for!